Im getting this error in Next js : Export encountered errors on following paths: /Cartoon/page: /Cartoon
Whenever I try to deploy my project on firebase, I get this error in the terminal:

Export encountered errors on following paths:
/Cartoon/page: /Cartoon

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Here's the code:
export default async function page({ name }) {
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=24a1f89401be144ce02466512297e932&query=${name}&include_adult=true&language=en-US&page=1`)
    let cartoon = await response.json();
    console.log(cartoon)
    return (
        <div className='h-72 w-40 rounded-xl'>
            <div>
                <a href={name}><img className='rounded-t-xl' src={`https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2${cartoon.results[0].poster_path}`} /></a>
            </div>
            <div className='h-12 rounded-b-xl bg-zinc-900 flex items-center justify-center p-2'>
                <h4 className='h-fit'>{cartoon.results[0].name}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


I tried to use getStaticProps(), axios and use client, but none solved the problem.

Where is the name parameter supposed to come from? Is it a query param (/Cartoon?name=...)? If so, you should use the parameter searchParams:
export default async function page({ searchParams : {name} }) {

it comes from the dynamic route. When the user enters the name of a cartoon and search it, it passed as a parameter from the dynamic route to this component.
